# Issue with HomeController showing undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify-app

I am trying to pass stored_products from shopify into a Rails app but keep getting a home controller error at https://f588240c.ngrok.io/ i have made updates, with no luck and restarted the server a number of times with no luck.

[image]

Any help would be welcomed. Heres the code

```
class Api::V1::HomeController < ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController
def index
@products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { limit: 10 })

@products.each do |product|
      StoredProduct.where(shopify_id: product.id)
      .first_or_create do |stored_product|
        stored_product.shopify_id = product.id
        stored_product.shopify_title = product.title
        stored_product.shopify_handle = product.handle
        stored_product.shopify_image_url = product.image.src
        stored_product.shop_id = @shop.id
        stored_product.save

        product.images.each do |image|
          ProductImage.where(shopify_id: image.id)
            .first_or_create do |product_image|
              product_image.image_url = image.src
              product_image.stored_product_id = stored_product_id
              product_image.shopify_id = image.id
          end
        end

      end
    end
  @stored_products = StoredProduct.belongs_to_shop(@shop.id)
  end
end
```

From the authenticated controller

```
    private
      def set_shop
        @shop = Shop.find_by(id: session[:shopify])
        set_locale
      end
```

from the store_products.rb file

```
class StoredProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
  has_many :product_images

  scope :belongs_to_shop, -> shop_id { where(shop_id: shop_id) }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific issue/code tutorial, the private set_shop method should be set like follows:

```
def set_shop
  @shop = Shop.find_by(id: session[:shop_id])
  set_locale
end
```

The other answer has `params` instead of `session`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `@shop` is nil. The error message says it cannot call the method `.id` on NilClass.

In the image I can see that you have a shop_id in the params so you might just need to change your code here:

```
def set_shop
        @shop = Shop.find_by(id: params[:shop_id])
        set_locale
      end
```

But that depends on your code, so please double check.

Comment: Happy to help!!